# Using post in define

Tags: php, constants, config

```
<?php
$rootdir = "digiAdmin"; //leave if no folder
define("CONFIG","true");
//    Database Config    //
define('DB_HOST', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
define("DB_USER", $_POST['DB_USER']);
define("DB_PASS", $_POST['DB_PASSWORD']);
define("DB_NAME", $_POST['DB_NAME']);
```

I have a form which will ask for database `name`, `username` and `password`. when I click on submit button it show me an error. I have defined this config and made a function which is checking config is true or false. I am using post to get the username, password and database name. Am I doing in a correct way?

Comment: I think you don't post always the username and password. Take alook at sessions. That is what you want.

Comment: "when i click on submit button it show me an error" - what error?

Comment: What kind of error you've got?

Comment: **Notice**: Undefined index: DB_USER in C:\xampp\htdocs\digiAdmin\appconfig.php on line 7

**Notice**: Undefined index: DB_PASSWORD in C:\xampp\htdocs\digiAdmin\appconfig.php on line 8

**Notice**: Undefined index: DB_NAME in C:\xampp\htdocs\digiAdmin\appconfig.php on line 9

Comment: Are you 100% positive the $_POST contains these values? Try debugging it like print_r($_POST).

Comment: `$_POST` doesn't contain these values. Perhaps a problem with upper/lower case. If you show the HTML form, we'll see this.

Comment: And make sure the form method is post.

Comment: i have checked everything . DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS and DB_NAME have the respective value which i am posting but when i go to use the database , it said database cannot b selected –

Comment: @NishitBhardwaj: Could you please provide 1. a `print_r($_POST);` right before your defines, 2. a snippet of your HTML form containing the form tag, input fields, submit buttons and such and 3. the code where you try to connect to the database (and perhaps 4. the exact error message when trying to connect to the database - the database exists and the user has access rights to it, I suppose...)? Thank you.

Comment: @stef77 , can i have ur email-id so that i can send u my code .

Comment: @stef77 send me your id ya my id nish.discoverme@gmail.com

Comment: @NishitBhardwaj Can't you edit your question with the "edit" link under the badges "php", "config" and "define"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, based on your comments I'd like to try to answer your question.

This should be your PHP script db.php (the mysql_* methods are actually deprecated, but that's a story for another day to keep this simple):

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
define("DB_USER", $_POST['DB_USER']);
define("DB_PASS", $_POST['DB_PASSWORD']);
define("DB_NAME", $_POST['DB_NAME']);

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die ("Can't use db: " . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

And this might be your HTML page index.html:

```
<form action="db.php" method="post">
 User: <input type="text" name="DB_USER"><br>
 Pass: <input type="text" name="DB_PASSWORD"><br>
 DB: <input type="text" name="DB_NAME"><br>
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

According to your question, you get some errors somewhere, so db.php will probably die with the corresponding message. If so, you can try this:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("host", "user", "password");

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("db", $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die ("Can't use db: " . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Which means not using posted variables but strings you know they work.

If even the second script fails, your data (user, password and/or database) is incorrect. If the second script succeeds, there may be something wrong with the form you post.

Comment: thanks for your help , i solved my problem . I am just a beginner  , i made a silly mistake .

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if those POST values are set, try this:

```
define('DB_HOST', isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] : null);
define("DB_USER", isset($_POST['DB_USER']) ? $_POST['DB_USER'] : null);
define("DB_PASS", isset($_POST['DB_PASSWORD']) ? $_POST['DB_PASSWORD'] : null);
define("DB_NAME", isset($_POST['DB_NAME']) ? $_POST['DB_NAME'] : null);
```

Comment: I have put your code in my page and I checked it .  DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS and DB_NAME have the respective value which i am posting but when i go to use the database , it said database cannot b selected

Comment: @NishitBhardwaj do you use the database in the same script as the `define` or the different one?

Comment: thanks for your help , i solved my problem . I am just a beginner  , i made a silly mistake .